# Prove that $d$ is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, linear-transformations

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and let $d:\,R_n[X]\to R_n[X]$ be the derivative linear transformation, s.t. $d(P)=P'$.

I know that map f : V → W is said to be linear, if for any u and v vectors in V , for any real number λ, we have

(1) f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v),

(2) f(λu) = λf(u).

How can I prove exactly that the operation of taking derivatives satisfies  the sum rule, and the condition with taking out a constant?

Also, how can I find the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of $d$? I have found the associated matrix $A$ but I have no idea how to do so here:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 &  \dots  & n-1 \\
0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Re: the characteristic polynomial, you have an upper-triangular matrix. What are its eigenvalues and their algebraic multiplicities?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For the linearity, what could be $d(\lambda P+Q)$ where $P,Q$ are polynomial and $\lambda \in\mathbb R$ ?

For the caracteristic/minimal polynomial, remark that $d^{n+1}(X^m)=0$ for all $m\leq n$. I recall that $d^n=\underbrace{d\circ ...\circ d}_{n\ times}$.